# Polarity free dc circuit module

Tags: input, polarity

I am looking for a chip or a circuit module in which the output will be dc voltage in certain pins positive + and negative - , no matter how the dc input is connected, normal +- or or reverse -+.  The range is: 5V-30V 1A.

Comment: Do you want a bridge rectifier?

Answer (score 3):

You are describing a bridge rectifier but before you rush out and buy one, there are a few caveats:

- Bridge rectifiers are made to change AC into pulsating DC. In this mode of operation, one pair of diodes will be conducting during one half-cycle of the input waveform and the other pair will be conducting on the other half-cycle. In your application, one pair will be conducting continually and the other will not. This has implications for heat dissipation, so I would play it safe and choose a rectifier with an average rectified current of at least *twice* the current draw you plan to use.  Depending on the module, you may still need to use a heatsink.
- Since bridge rectifiers use opposing pairs of diodes to pass current, you will have a double diode voltage drop from the input to the output. The magnitude depends on the module but will be at least a volt or so. If your device needs at least 5V, then your supply should be at least 7V, or use an ideal diode bridge controller.

Comment: Schottky diode bridge rectifiers should be able to do lower voltage drops, but yes, expect some voltage drop, as specified for your current as stated in the rectifier's datasheet!